# exclude CommandLineRunner execution in the test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've got `main` class that looks like this

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:hideutilityclassconstructor") // FIXME:doesn't work
@ComponentScan({"com.lapots.breed.judge"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class JudgeRuleEngineApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JudgeRuleEngineApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner initCache(final InMemoryPlayerLevelCache cache) {
        return args -> {
            cache.put(1, 100);
            cache.put(2, 1000);
            cache.put(3, 10000);
            cache.put(4, 100000);
        };
    }
}
```

On startup I initialize my `cache` with values.
But during test I want to prevent that - I want to exclude the `commandlinerunner` from the execution

My test looks like this

```
@WebFluxTest(excludeFilters =
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = CommandLineRunner.class))
class InMemoryPlayerLevelCacheTestSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    InMemoryPlayerLevelCache cache

    def "should access cache"() {
        when:
            cache.put(10, 200)
        then:
            1 == cache.size()
            200 == cache.get(10)
    }
}
```

I tried to exclude it using `excludeFilter` but still my test fails because it has more elements than expect (should have 1 but it has 5 as 1 in test + 4 initialization).

What is wrong?